# ASP.net MVC with Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

Does anybody know of an up to date tutorial on using Ajax with ASP.net MVC?  Most of what I can find seems to talk about older versions of MVC and I suspect that this is an area where there has been a lot of change of late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stephen Walter just blogged about this:
http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/09/22/asp-net-mvc-application-building-forums-6-ajax.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Stephen Walter's post "[ASP.NET MVC Application Building: Forums #6 – Ajax](http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/09/22/asp-net-mvc-application-building-forums-6-ajax.aspx)" seems to be focused on Microsoft ASP.NET AJAX.

A quick search on google for "[ASP.NET MVC jquery](http://www.google.ca/search?q=asp.net+mvc+jquery&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)" brings up several resources on non-MS javascript.

I lean towards the non-MS AJAX demos & tutorials as they show platform-agnostic patterns and practices.

Comment: ASP.NET AJAX libraries are platform agnostic... they are just javascript.

Comment: just javascript, true, but with a .NET flavor of syntax and structure to their API.  One of the stated goals of ASP.NET AJAX is to provide .NET developers with familiar method signatures and behavior, where reasonable, to ease their transition to client-side development.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for form-releated Ajax support in MVC, check out Scott Hanselman's post:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCPreview4UsingAjaxAndAjaxForm.aspx

It seems there isn't currently good support for end-to-end validation with Ajax forms. Most articles I've read use a combination of a client-side library and server-side data annotations. I'm hoping the full beta release of MVC will include better support.

Also, be sure to note that Microsoft will be including jQuery as an officially supported library for Ajax development. Scott Guthrie annoinced this at:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/28/jquery-and-microsoft.aspx